# Bootstrap working via link, but not when downloaded

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot

I am trying to do some website by using Bootstrap and Spring Boot.

When I put web location of `bootstrap.min.css` in `href`, it is working perfectly.

**Code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

But when I download the same library and put it in a folder, Bootstrap is not recognized at my website.

**Code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap-4.5.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Can someone explain me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Wrong file location? Please check your browser inspector Network tab and look for css requests.

Comment: I manage to figure this out.
It had to be in the same folder as index.html.
I previously put it in static folder, but when I moved it in the same folder as index.html, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to figure this out. Despite the fact that location of file is in `static`, Spring boot recognizes automatically that it is in `static`, so it is enough to write `href="/bootstrap-4.5.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`.